# How to find center (x,y) pixel of the monitor on a mac in Chrome or Firefox?

Tags: javascript, macos

This is related to rendering and graphics.

In Windows, my work around is to detect full screen mode, then prompt the user to press F11, then everything is ez-pz.

On mac, there is really no such thing as full screen mode, its just maximized with the address bar and button stuck to the top.

Is there at least a way to figure how the height of stuff at the top so I can subtract that distance to find the true center relative to the monitor itself?

Comment: FYI: Mac Chrome and Firefox both have fullscreen mode, the page has to request it. Example: http://fscreen.rafrex.com/

Comment: Oh awesome, I didn't know that :)

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the bottom of your viewport is flush with the bottom of the screen, you can find the offset from the top of the screen to the top of the viewport:

```
let offset = window.screen.height - window.innerHeight;
```

Comment: Okay, maybe we have to check screen.width == innerWidth and hope its indeed maximized (e.g flush). This is one area where FF > Chrome since it has an easy boolean. window.fullScreen